# Bootstrap dynamically resize row height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know how to resize images that are shown on the screen so that their heights are all the same.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container img-content">
<div class="row">
    <h2 class="text-center text-muted title">Image Gallery With Effects</h2>
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 limit shrink "><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/1/" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 limit shrink  "><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 limit shrink "><img class="img-responsive" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/d/d2/Mrtallimage.png/revision/latest?cb=20130222100629" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 limit shrink "><img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/%22You_must_be_this_tall_to_have_your_own_religion.%22_(Imagicity_366).jpg"/></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gray"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/5/" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shrink "><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/6/" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 vertpan"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/7/" /></div>
</div>
```

This produces:
[image]

Is it possible to satisfy all of these:

1. View all unstretched images.
2. Limit the height of all images to a predetermined value so they are all level.
3. No picture should be cropped.

If there are better ways to do this, please suggest so. Thanks!

Comment: You can specify fixed height to all the images using css `height` property but this will force your taller images to squeeze. Better use images with same dimensions.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way to "center" the images in the bootstrap grid system where the columns are of size 12.

Comment: use `text-align` center for that

Comment: @Fuad You can use `img{text-align: center;}` for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Bootstrap 4, check out [flexbox](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/).